# Syntax error in assembly when using letter "C"

Tags: assembly

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
A = 2
B = 5
C = 3
D = 4

.code
main proc
    ;A = (A + B) + (C + D)  A = 14

    ;A = (A + B)
    mov EBP, A
    ADD EBP, B

    ;A = A + (C + D)
    mov EDI, C
    add EDI, D
    add EDI, EBP ;Total



    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

The error that is shown in Visual Studio 2013 is "Error A2008: syntax error: C". This error is shown twice in a row.

Comment: Haha! You said `DOWRD` ;)

Comment: Looks like a _tpyo_..

Comment: Yea I should of used a "="

Comment: So there no longer is an error in your question?

Comment: Error is still there. I just don't understand what is wrong with "C". Is it the letter or something.

Comment: Here's an Old stunt from decades ago:  In order to test what's wrong with that line, change `C` to `Fred_C` and see if the problem goes away. After that, change it back to `C` and see if it returns.  If both cases happen as predicted, then you are using a forbidden word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `C` happens to be one of the [*language type* names](http://www.siliconkit.com/rebecca/help/masmpguide/Chap_12.htm) used by some of MASM's directives, e.g. `.MODEL` and `PUBLIC` - that's why you can't use it as a name for your own symbols. You'll just have to pick another name.